# Detect Key Combination / Double Taps in Android

Tags: android

I would like to detect key combination in Android, say I want to open up the search feature of my application when the user presses MENU+S.

Any good way to do it?

EDIT : I know that I could make a button, but lets just that I do not want to take up screen space at all. So figured that key combinations would be the best way to go, only I cant think of any good way to detect them. Does android provide any api of some sort which I can use?

EDIT : Stephan pointed out this interesting idea, which did intrigue me.

> Notice that the soft keyboard could use key combos, but it
>   specifically doesn't and it's so much better because of that. For
>   instance, to capitalize one letter, in Android you don't press the
>   shift key at the same time of the letter, you press the shift key
>   once, and then you press the letter (and then your shift key
>   automatically becomes unpressed). I personally find that usability
>   flow to work fantastically well on a phone where it's difficult to
>   coordinate more than one finger at the same time.

But unfortunately I cannot use this design as I would like the keyboard buttons to retain default behaviour.

EDIT : I could go for double taps too if its easier to detect than combos, but again I have no idea how to detect key double taps.
Thank you Stephan, again, for another brilliant idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's a good idea? Wouldn't it be easier to override the search button for that?

Do you own an actual Android phone that you're using personally? I realize that some Android developers are still using iPhones primarily and aren't really familiar with the Android interface aside from the phone that they're given to test on at work.

Notice that the soft keyboard could use key combos, but it specifically doesn't and it's so much better because of that. For instance, to capitalize one letter, in Android you don't press the shift key at the same time of the letter, you press the shift key once, and then you press the letter (and then your shift key automatically becomes unpressed). I personally find that usability flow to work fantastically well on a phone where it's difficult to coordinate more than one finger at the same time.

Comment: Well, lets just that I want to do it with key combinations.

Comment: Well I do own an Android phone, and it is an interesting thing you pointed out. I will rethink my design, but in the meanwhile I would be grateful if you could give me some idea about how to detect key combinations. I'd prefer to have more options.

Comment: Location doesn't matter right now. You see, one reason I want to use key combination is because I would like every button to behave normally when pressed, but I want something special to happen only when a combination is pressed. The SHIFT key is a specially designed key, so I guess when it is pressed Android just toggles the state of the CAPS. But I cannot have my own custom key. If the user presses the MENU button, I would want to show him a menu. So I guess I have to go with combos.

Comment: Ah ok, have you considered doing long presses (or doing two successive taps) of the same key/button? Have you considered swipes/gestures in different directions? Some applications use those different ways of doing shortcuts very successfully (in any case, I have to go now, I'll reply tomorrow if someone else hasn't done it by then).

Comment: I do not want to use long presses as they kind of slows down the user. If I am creating a shortcut, I would want it to be fast. I have misgivings about swipes/gestures, hard to remember; and again, combos are faster. Double taps could work, but I don't know how to detect them without hindering default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also agree with the search button is a bad design of android.
You can follow the onKeyDown method

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) { 
  // start a thread and let it stop in a while 
} else if(keyCode == YOURDEFINECODE ){ 
  // if the thread has been running do what you want
} else { 
  // stop the thread
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I didnt get you. Could you please explain a bit more. Especially what you mean by `keyCode == YOURDEFINECODE`.

Comment: I don't know weather you want to do it in the activity or in the widget. My idea is to start a thread when user clicked the menu button, you can handle this in the onKeyDown method. It will exist a while like 5 seconds or more to wait for your next action, and after that it should disappear itself. During these time if the user clicked the key you defined you can jump into the activity you want, if they clicked the other key, just simply stop the thread.